# Convert abstract class from object to pointer with a function

Tags: c++

Basically I want to convert abstract class reference or object to pointer of that object, I couldn't find anything on the internet. I know i can do just &object but i want to make a function that takes object and returns pointer. For example:
GameObject * convert(GameObject & object)
I need a function for that becouse i have a lua scripts that handle objects so i can mod my game easier.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the purpose having a function to do that? Reference counting?

Comment: What's wrong with `GameObject * convert(GameObject & object) {return &object;}`?

Comment: The problem is GameObject is an abstract class so it will give an error: cannot instantiate abstract class.

Comment: @Orion you cannot create a stand alone instance of an abstract class.

Comment: The above `convert` works just fine assuming you already have a `GameObject`.  Creating a `GameObject` is a different issue, and not what your question seems to be asking about.

Comment: The suggestion of Knoep will not give that error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.This function is in the standard library. It is called `std::addressof`.

It was introduced in C++11, so in case your standard library is too old, then:

> I know i can do just &object

Simply write a function and use the address of operator there, as you just know you can do. (The trivial implementation has a caveat that the addressof operator may be overloaded to not return the address. This can be avoided, but I feel is out of scope of my answer).

---

> The problem is GameObject is an abstract class so it will give an error: cannot instantiate abstract class.

That is not a problem with getting the address of a `GameObject`. That is a problem with creating an instance of `GameObject`. You cannot instantiate objects of an abstract class except as base class sub object.